# Ubuntu 16.04 (guest) fails start on VirtualBox (Win7 host): LSB, Raise, Login Service and Accounts Service

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

My Ubuntu 16.04 fails to start on Win7 host (VBox 5.0.20) as shown below
Ubuntu 16.04 stuck to start:

[image]

Any hints are very appreciated.

Thanks,

UPDATE: I can access recovery mode normally, but don't know how to fix.